# Usage of の全然だよ by itself?

Tags: word-choice, reading-comprehension

Context: Two characters are talking: Character A teaches B about her work, however A tells B a lot of things all at once.

Character B says:

> 新しいことを知るのは楽しいです。香苗さんの話面白いし
> Basically "Understanding new things is fun. And you talk about interesting stuff"

To which she replies

> よかった。まあ昔から叩き込まれたことだから　こんなの全然だよ

I understand her answer is "I'm glad. But because this is stuff I got drilled into since a long time ago, this is...."

I'm not sure how to take 全然 here? Completely different? Extreme? She seems to draw a comparison over learning from a young age vs having it explained in one session

Comment: Is there not a typo? There usually wouldn't be two の's in こんなのの全然だよ.

Answer (score 1):

From the provided text alone, it sounds like something similar to 全然何でもない or 全然大したことない.

The comparison is between こんなの (which I assume refers to the explaining) and what may look like to B. So if it can look like a lot from B's viewpoint, 全然だよ means it is not that much and/or explaining that much is nothing burdensome to A.